# Using the same CSS values as in Figma design, produce different values

Tags: html, css, figma

I am trying to implement a design from figma but notice it isnt always accurate:

This is the input field i want to create:

[image]

Notice how the thin the text is. These are the values from figma:

```
color: var(--heading-black, #222);
/* Button/16/Regular */
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 16px;
```

I also use the same color and font-weight, I even tried using 100 instead of 400, yet my result is:

[image]

My text is much thicker and I dont know why. This is my css code for my input field:

```
.search-field {
    margin-left: 65px;
    width: 429px;
    height: 44px;   
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 46px;
    background: url("../../../assets/icons/search.png") no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 21px;
    background-position: 14px center;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    color: #222;
}
```

and html:

```
<input type="text" class="search-field" value placeholder="Booking.com, Expedia, Otto...">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `font-family` property and it's value in your selector and also use the cdn I used here cause it has all the available font-weights embedded in it.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Open+Sans&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');

.search-field{font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Open+Sans&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');

body{
  background: green;
}

.search-field {
    margin-left: 65px;
    width: 429px;
    height: 44px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 46px;
    background: url("../../../assets/icons/search.png") no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 21px;
    background-position: 14px center;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    color: #222;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-field" value placeholder="Booking.com, Expedia, Otto...">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting the same result even if you change the font-weight value, it means you're having one of these problems:

1. Your font does not have or you have not imported the desired weight value (example: you want 100 but the closest value you have included in the @font face is 400 );
2. Check that there are no other rules that are not overwriting it;

Last thing, in this case you want to change the appearance of the placeholder so you will have to use the pseudo element ::placeholder so you can change only the style of the placeholder without running the risk of having other problems.

In the code, I provided the placeholder with a lighter color so as to simulate the result.

```css
.search-input{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #21A668;
    padding: 10px;
}

.search-field{
    width: 429px;
    height: 44px;   
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 10px 0 46px;
    background: url("../../../assets/icons/search.png") no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 21px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    color: #222;
}

.search-field::placeholder{
    color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

```html
    <div class="search-input">
        <input type="text" class="search-field" value placeholder="Booking.com, Expedia, Otto...">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your input is getting its weight from another class or tag.
Try using `!important` for the `font-weight` and see if it works:

```css
font-weight: 400 !important;
```

Comment: this didnt work

Answer (score 0):

@MdRakibulIslam has pointed me in the right direction. In my global styles.scss I had this code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Inter;
}
```

I used `Inter` but apparently u have to import it. So adding

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200..900');
```

made it work. Thanks for the answers!